# change all .sh files to executable by terminal

Tags: macos, script

i hate retyping chmod +x filename and insect to run from terminal. how do i set    this for all .sh files ? I've tried Inspect then manually setting the extension

Comment: Permissions are attached to each file, and not a file type. are you looking for a way to iterate the filesystem and automate dozens or thousands of changes or is this more a software recommendation to make a helper app that does things on demand?

Answer (score 5):

Using a `find` command would be simple enough:

```
find . -iname "*.sh" -exec bash -c 'chmod +x "$0"' {} \;
```

The command breaks down as
`find` [obvious!]
`.` = from this folder. You can put a path instead
`-iname` = case insensitive name
`"*.sh"` = wildcard filename
`-exec` = utility to execute commands
`bash` = what tool you want to use (you can use `sh` instead)
`-c` flag means execute the following command as interpreted by this program.
`chmod +x` = command to change the file to executable
`"$0"` = The value that was passed to the utility
`{}` = If the string `{}` appears anywhere in the utility name or the arguments it is replaced by the pathname of the current file.
`;` = Terminates the command

Comment: Nice explanation; however, you did not explain the _backslash_ before the _semicolon_, but did explain all the other _arguments_ of the _command_. I'm sure there are many users that don't understand why or even that the _semicolon_ is being escaped by the _backslash_ as it's a _special character_ to the _shell_, and if not escaped `find` would complain with `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`. The `;` could also be placed in quotes, e.g. `';'`, but why type an extra character when a single _backslash_ will do. :)

Comment: Actually, `iname "*.sh"` interprets as files that end with `.sh`, `.SH`, `.sH`, or `Sh`.

Comment: @user3439894 Well spotted. Forgot to explain the escape char! Thanks for adding.

Comment: @fd0 Covers those who have fat fingers when saving files (I have on occasion saved files with varied case extensions!)